# Script or opensource code to rotate node eks nodes in Autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Whenever I am updating eks version, I have to manually cordon and drain all the nodes in all autoscaling groups. Is there any utility available that can help me do this. Any opensource tool or script that can help me reduce this task

Comment: is it managed node group?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [managed node group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html).

When you update a managed node group version to the latest AMI release version for your node group's Kubernetes version or to a newer Kubernetes version to match your cluster, Amazon EKS triggers the following logic:

1. Amazon EKS creates a new Amazon EC2 launch template version for the
   Auto Scaling group associated with your node group. The new template
   uses the target AMI for the update.
2. The Auto Scaling group is updated to use the latest launch template
   with the new AMI.
3. The Auto Scaling group maximum size and desired size are incremented
   by one up to twice the number of Availability Zones in the Region
   that the Auto Scaling group is deployed in. This is to ensure that
   at least one new instance comes up in every Availability Zone in the
   Region that your node group is deployed in.
4. Amazon EKS checks the nodes in the node group for the
   `eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image` label, and applies a
   `eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=unschedulable:NoSchedule` taint on all of
   the nodes in the node group that aren't labeled with the latest AMI
   ID. This prevents nodes that have already been updated from a
   previous failed update from being tainted.
5. Amazon EKS randomly selects a node in the node group and evicts all
   pods from it.
6. After all of the pods are evicted, Amazon EKS cordons the node. This
   is done so that the service controller doesn't send any new request
   to this node and removes this node from its list of healthy, active
   nodes.
7. Amazon EKS sends a termination request to the Auto Scaling group for
   the cordoned node.
8. Steps 5-7 are repeated until there are no nodes in the node group
   that are deployed with the earlier version of the launch template.
9. The Auto Scaling group maximum size and desired size are decremented
   by 1 to return to your pre-update values.

Further information can be found in [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-update-behavior.html).